# Bash copy only file content to another file

Tags: bash

I have a requirement where a file already exists with the name b.props. I am creating another file b1.props in another location with a different content. What I want to do is just copy the content of b1.props to b.props which means it shouldn't delete the file and then create because b.props has symlinks associated with it.

How can I do it via bash?

The other option for me is to write content to b.props but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: _just copy the content of b1.props to b.props_ --> you want to copy the content of b1.props and append to b.props?

Comment: Symlinks will not be affected if you delete the file and then recreate it. There may be a race condition if someone references the symlink at the precise moment when you have deleted the original file and not yet created its replacement; if this is a problem, you will need to arrange for some sort of locking mechanism, which typically requires cooperation from the processes which try to read the file.

Comment: `The other option for me is to write content to b.props` probably a file editor.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to **append** the contents of `b1.prop` to the existing contents of `b.prop` or whether you want to **replace** the contents of `b.prop` with the contents from `b1.prop`. Make that clear before a definitive answer can be given. @Jetchisel you may as well cover both cases in your answer, e.g. `>` and `>>`, or if it is replace, then simply `[ -s "b.prop" ] && cp b1.prop b.prop`

Comment: @Hasshit : **copying** already means that the original is not deleted. If you put a document into a copying machine, you don't expect the original to be destroyed, do you? If we want the original to be gone, we call it _moving_ or _renaming_, not _copying_. See _man cp_ on how to copy files.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, right, I'm still waiting for the OP's clarification, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the `cat` and redirection from the shell.

```
cat b1.props >> b.props
```

The `>>` will append the contents of b1 to b

Use `>` if you want to replace the content of b to b1

Of course use the correct/absolute path of both files.